# "Unable to enumerate the Downloadable Content offerings" error when trying to install Borderlands 2 Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode

Tags: borderlands-2

I just bought and downloaded the **Borderlands 2 Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode**, I go into the game, went to **Downloadable Content** to install it but every time I select **Downloadable Content** it says "enumerating downloadable content offerings...". Once that's done it just says "Unable to enumerate the Downloadable Content offerings. Please try again later."

Does anyone know why it's not working?

Comment: Are you by any chance using steam at the moment?? I had a similar issue with the sir hammerlock DLC not working and what I did to fix the issue was verify the game as certain files had not downloaded and installed correctly. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

As much as I wish I could tell you whats wrong the best advice would be go into your memory device now this part varies so read close:

1. **If you have season pass**, delete and download the pass, again. This has worked for me.
2. For SOL, you may be boned. Gearbox hasn't quite worked out all of the kinks for the DLC downloading process, so you may just be stuck until they can patch up the process.